# Почему не работает регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое находит в числе позицию группы разрядов (по 3 нуля): `(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`, однако я не понимаю, почему не работает то же регулярное выражение, которые выглядит немного по-другому: `(?<=\d)(?=(\d{3})+)(?!\d)`

Первый вариант работает:

[image]

Второй вариант не работает:

[image]

1 вариант (работает): https://regex101.com/r/ZcAFqj/1

2 вариант (не работает): https://regex101.com/r/ZcAFqj/2

Вопрос: почему во 2 варианте не выполняется последнее условие?

Comment: Ох и заморачиваетесь же вы! )) Потому что не стоит злоупотреблять вперёд|назад-просмотрами, т.к. это очень сказывается на производительности. Сравните ваши варианты с [моим](https://regex101.com/r/ZcAFqj/3) и сделайте выводы.

Comment: @Эдуард спасибо, но ответ был интересен, в первую очередь, с точки зрения самообразования - хотел узнать почему именно не работает код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Полагаю все дело в семантике...в первом варианте проверка и фиксация этой проверки идет вместе с последним блоком.

То есть в первом варианте регулярке для фиксации и переходна на след символ интересны только те 3 ноля, поcле которых нету цифр...И он или находит одно единственное удовлетворение своим желанием или не одного...
а во втором варианте ему просто нужны 3 цифры, а потом он на одном из шагов (смещение с фиксацией посимвольное происходит) внезапно для себя замечает, что он еще не набрал 3 ноля, а впереди уже и нету "не цифры"

Я подобное поведение встречал с и с жадным поиском (правда уже не помню какой был случай, что искал и где)...Но Эдуард прав, с этими просмотрами во времени лучше не злоупотреблять